# make an R function that count rows without NA in multiple files

Tags: r, function

I wrote this R function to go through csv files read them then exclude rows with NA values and return the count of rows in each file. it only work with the last file, but I want to get the no of rows for each file.

```
complete <- function(directory, id= 1:332) {
           file.list <- list.files(directory, full.names = T)
           dat <- data.farme()
           for(i in id) {
            dat <- read.csv(list.files[i])
           }
           complete_rows <- dat[complete.cases(dat),]
           nobs <- nrows(complete_rows)
           out <- data.frame(id, nobs)
           out
       }
```

when I run it and call the function: complete(directory, 25:30)
I get:
  id  nobs
1 25  932
2 26  932
3 27  932
4 28  932
ect... it is only returning the row count of the last file in the specified range... how can I fix that? thanks

Comment: Yup its for R programming class

Comment: the for loop go through the files but the number of rows that gets printed is only for the last file processed

Comment: if I used rbind it give me the total of all files

Comment: I don't want that either

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to change.  In your `for` loop you should be using `file.list` instead of `list.files`.  Also, the `for` loop is overwriting `dat` before you calculate the number of complete rows, so you end up with just getting the complete rows for the last file.  You can replace the `for` loop with an `apply` function which is generally what is done in R.

```
complete <- function(directory, id= 1:332) {
    file.list <- list.files(directory, full.names = T)

    ## Replace for loop with:
    counts <- sapply(id, function(i) {
        dat <- read.csv(file.list[i])
        sum(complete.cases(dat))
    })
    data.frame(id=id, rowCounts = counts)
}
```

If you want to keep the `for` loop you could do

```
counts <- rep(NA, length(id))
for (i in id) {
    dat <- read.csv(file.list[i])
    counts[i] <- sum(complete.cases(dat))
}
```

Comment: is it possible to show me the same trick within a for loop? I am so used to Python and would like to know how this function can be implemented using a for loop. Thank you for your response

Comment: well I tried the first method it worked but the for loop got me back again to were I was